# Different mysql trigger from C app and mysql console

Tags: mysql, c, character, collation, database-trigger

I have a strange question. I have created a C program, that creates triggers on mysql database. There is one problem with that. When I create triggers manually from mysql console, everything works fine, but when my C program creates triggers, they are some kind a different and it crashes and mysql restarts. There are the differences:

GOOD(manually created):

[image: good]

BAD(C program created):

[image: bad]

Everything seems the same except ***character_set_client*** and ***collation_connection*** that you can see at the bottom right.

Any solution or more information if needed?

Answer (score 0):

Probably guessing a bit here but I think you need to emit SQL statements to set `character_set_client` and `collation_connection` before or when you create the trigger. Your C code client probably is using some kind of default